# Archive Failed when trying "xcodebuild archive" in terminal - Doesn't include currently selected device

Tags: xcode, archive, xcodebuild

Systems: xcode 13, OS Monterey 12.5

1. Summarize the problem: My goal is to archive an iOS xcode project from command line using the xcodebuild archive command. I have my iPhone connected and xcode recognizes this device. I am able to archive this project by selecting xcode Product/Archive in the xcode IDE but for some reason when I run the xcodebuild archive command below I get the Archive Failed error that states,"Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile" doesn't include the currently selected device". The currently selected device stated in the error is my computer I.D. and not the iPhone I have connected. Again, this runs fine when I archive in xcode GUI so it seems my following command in terminal is incorrect.

I tried the fix in other related stackoverflow questions but they did not resolve my specific issue.

command: `xcodebuild archive -target AnalyzeSourceCode.xcworkspace \ -scheme AnalyzeSourceCode \ BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \ SKIP_INSTALL=NO`

I have tried various combinations of the command:

*Specifying workspace and destination:

```
xcodebuild -workspace AnalyzeSourceCode \               
-scheme AnalyzeSourceCode \
-destination generic/platform=iOS build
```

*Also ran trace on devices to confirm my iPhone is recognized which it is because I see it in finder and in xcode GUI.

```
xcrun xctrace list devices
```

It seems that my xcodebuild command is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found in Apple Forum: LINK: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668952

The post originator (Namzak) had the same issue and the archive failure was due to not including the destination when running xcodebuild command in terminal when archiving the project.

The key to my solution was the destination line below:

```
-destination 'generic/platform=iOS'
```

Complete Command I Execute:

```
xcodebuild archive -scheme APP_NAME_HERE \
-configuration Release \
-destination 'generic/platform=iOS' \
-archivePath "APP_NAME_HERE.xcarchive"
```